# How to allow deleting of array items in Apostrophe array object

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have a pretty extensive site built on top of Apostrophe-CMS, heavily utilizing object schemas and the admin editor interfaces. I've been having a problem with arrays for a very long time, and I've never been able to figure out what's happening. This seems to happen with every array I define, but here's a specific example (this is an added field on apostrophe-users):

```
{
name: 'subscriptions',
label: 'Memberships',
type: 'array',
titleField: 'subscriptionYear',
schema: [
    {
        name: '_subscription',
        withType: 'subscription-type',
        type: 'joinByOne',
        idField: 'subscriptionId',
        filters: {
            projection: {
                type: 1,
                name: 1,
                description: 1,
                agreement: 1,
                familyMembers: 1,
                title: 1,
                _allowedGroup: 1,
                allowedGroupId: 1,
                price: 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'expirationDate',
        label: 'Expiration Date',
        type: 'date',
        required: false
    },
    {
        name: 'waiverSignature',
        label: 'Waiver Signature',
        type: 'string',
        readOnly: true
    },
    {
        name: '_payment',
        withType: 'payments',
        type: 'joinByOne',
        idField: 'paymentId',
        titleField: 'subscriptionType',
        filters: {
            projection: {
                paymentDate: 1,
                userEmail: 1,
                paymentAmount: 1,
                subscriptionType: 1,
                subscriptionYear: 1,
                receiptEmail: 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'familyMembers',
        label: 'Family Members',
        type: 'array',
        titleField: 'familyMemberName',
        schema: [
            {
                name: 'familyMemberName',
                label: 'Family Member Name',
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                name: 'familyMemberBirthDate',
                label: 'Family Member Birth Date',
                type: 'date'
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that deleting items from this array doesn't work unless you save the object first. If I try to delete an item from the array without saving the user first, the entry flickers in the list (disappears and almost immediately reappears). There are no console errors. But, if I open the user, save the user (even if no changes have been made), and then open the user again without closing the user pieces list, I'm able to remove items from the array and save again. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the steps to reproduce this problem. Am I correct that you 1) open a user to edit, 2) add one or more items to this top-level array, then 3) try to delete one, but it won't delete?

Comment: Close - whenever this happens, the items are already in the array from a prior edit. So its more like 1) open a user to edit, 2) open the array by clicking the Edit button, 3) click the X button to try to delete an item in the array. At that point, the only way I've found to delete the item is to save the entire user, then re-attempt steps 1-3. For some reason those steps work after the save.

Comment: This sounds like an edge case bug or a problem in the project. Can you reproduce it in a minimal test case? Does this happen without joins? I'm wondering if there's a problem with joined pieces (maybe they're joined to deleted items?)

Comment: Sure! I'll put together a very basic example and post a link to it here. Thank you!

Comment: I was actually able to figure out what's going on, but I'm not sure how to fix it correctly. In almost all cases, I have code that is adding items to the array problematically, as opposed to in the editor (usually we use the pieces editor to delete and edit existing items, except in rare cases). When an item containing an array is saved in the pieces editor, an id is automatically assigned to each array item. I'm not assigning that ID when I add items via code. Is there a good place to put code to add an ID to a piece's array if it doesn't already have one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a good place to put code to add an ID to a piece's array if it doesn't already have one?

Ultimately the problem seems to be about creating array values in code. The best place to add the ID would be when that value is first added. There's an Apostrophe utility method, `self.apos.utils.generateId()` that can be used for this purpose. If you're adding the value somewhere outside of Apostrophe, the [`cuid`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cuid) or [`uuid`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) utilities can help with that (the Apos method uses cuid).